# Passive or adjective information

Tags: participial-adjectives

> He will be satisfied.

I believe here "satisfied" is an adjective. But if I have to say it in passive form, it would remain same as

> Active : I will satisfy you.
> Passive : You will be satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in this case the adjective and the passive form are the same.  Moreover the meaning is also virtually the same. So it doesn't really matter.

The only difference is that the passive sentence implies that "someone satisfied him".  It implies the existence of an "actor". The adjective sentence doesn't imply this.  Since the sentence is ambiguous, it doesn't imply an actor, and so most people would parse this as being an adjective.

But as I said, it doesn't make much difference if you prefer to parse it as a passive sentence, since the meaning is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Is your question, "what part of speech is 'satisfied' in 'he will be satisfied?'"

> A [participle](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/gerunds_participles_and_infinitives/participles.html) is a verbal that is used as an adjective and most often ends in -ing or -ed. The term verbal indicates that a participle, like the other two kinds of verbals, is based on a verb and therefore expresses action or a state of being. However, since they function as adjectives, participles modify nouns or pronouns.

Answer (score 1):

"Satisfy" is also a **verb**, and "satisfied" is the past participle of that verb. Verbs can often be adjectives. For example, *to wash* is a more obvious verb. The past participle of this verb, "washed" (as in "*I washed the car*") can also be used as an adjective to describe something that has been washed (as in "*the washed car*").

Likewise, you gave the example of "I will satisfy you", so conversely you can say "you will be satisfied". It would be the same construction as if you said "I will help you", and "you will be helped".

If you view it as a verb, switching between active and passive voice makes much more sense.